# autoscrolling Div left to right?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to auto scroll an Div but instead of it going from top to bottom or from bottom to the top, I need it to go left to right!

I have found a code that does exactly what I need but it just goes bottom to top.

this is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

/***********************************************
* IFRAME Scroller script- © Dynamic Drive DHTML code library (www.dynamicdrive.com)
* This notice MUST stay intact for legal use
* Visit Dynamic Drive at http://www.dynamicdrive.com/ for full source code
***********************************************/

//Specify speed of scroll. Larger=faster (ie: 5)
var scrollspeed=cache=2

//Specify intial delay before scroller starts scrolling (in miliseconds):
var initialdelay=500

function initializeScroller() {
   dataobj = document.all? document.all.datacontainer :  
                           document.getElementById("datacontainer")
   dataobj.style.top = "5px"
   setTimeout("getdataheight()", initialdelay)
}

function getdataheight() {
   thelength=dataobj.offsetHeight
   if ( thelength == 0 )
       setTimeout("getdataheight()",10)
   else
       scrollDiv()
}

function scrollDiv() {
   dataobj.style.top=parseInt(dataobj.style.top)-scrollspeed+"px"
   if (parseInt( dataobj.style.top ) < thelength*( -1 ) )
       dataobj.style.top = "5px"
   setTimeout("scrollDiv()",40)
}

if (window.addEventListener)
   window.addEventListener("load", initializeScroller, false)
else if (window.attachEvent)
   window.attachEvent("onload", initializeScroller)
else
   window.onload=initializeScroller

</script>
```

anyone knows how to make this script to move the Div left to right instead of bottom to top?

by the way, I am very new to javascript so please be gentle.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two lines of code that say `dataobj.style.top="5px"` Try changing them to `dataobj.style.left="5px"` and see if that fixes it.

**Edit:** `dataobj.style.top=parseInt(dataobj.style.top)-scrollspeed+"px"` would also need to have "top" changed to "left."  Basically, your problem is, you're changing the wrong CSS property.

Comment: that did it. Thanks ever so much.